# Data lost from float assignment to float print

Tags: c, unit-testing, floating-accuracy

This came up during testing where I have to compare values between actual output and expected output.

Code:

```
float nf = 584227.4649743827f;
printf("Output: \t %.9f \n", nf);
```

Output:

```
Output:  584227.437500
```

I clearly have some gaps in my knowledge in C, so could someone explain to me this situation:

1. Why is there this deviation (`0.027474382659420f`) in the print ?
2. Is this only the limitation of print, or is it the float data type limitation?
3. which value is actually stored in the variable `nf`?
4. How should I work with values like this so I don't lose information like having a deviation of `0.027474382659420f` during assignment.

Any other suggestion related to this kind of problem in testing would be also much appriciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @Groo it's nore really a dupe, but the link you suggest is worth reading anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is there this deviation (0.027474382659420f) in the print ?

Because `float` has an accuracy of about 7 digits, and your deviation starts at the seventh digit.

> Is this only the limitation of print, or is it the float data type
>   limitation?

It's a limitation of floating point numbers, so that also includes `double` (although `double` has a higher precision). It also has to do with the conversion between binary and decimal numbers, so for instance `0.2` is a repeating decimal (well, binary) in binary representation, so it is suspect to rounding errors, too, and might actually turn into something like `0.200000000000000011`.

> which value is actually stored in the variable nf?

The one that you see printed. The `584227.4649743827f` that you specified most likely won't even exist in the binary of your compiled program and is "translated" to the actually used value during compilation.

> How should I work with values like this so I don't lose information
>   like having a deviation of 0.027474382659420f during assignment.

Use `double`, that has an accuracy of about 15-17 digits. Also, you need to remove the `f` from the `584227.4649743827f`, turning it into a `double` constant instead. If that is not accurate enough, you may have to use external libraries instead for arbitrary precision numbers, such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Your floating point numbers most likely adhere to the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: *"It's a limitation of floating point numbers"* That is only half of the problem. The major point missing is that there is decimal -> binary -> decimal conversion, and some numbers cannot exist on either numeric system without very high or infinite precision.

Comment: @user694733 Good point, that causes some of the most infamous "is floating point math broken" type errors, so I added a bit of an explanation on that.